# Can a private repo share a blobstore with a public repo?

Tags: nexus, blobstore

I'm using Nexus 3 as a repo manager. I have one repo that I want clients to have read only access to and devs to have read/edit/add access to, and another repo that I only want devs to be able to access. Can these repos share a blobstore or should they each have their own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can share a blobstore. This is just a physical location on disk where the files are stored, security is handled inside of Nexus Repo itself, and the blobstore just serves as an abstraction of the physical files. As long as your users do not have access to the physical file system, you should be fine, and even then the files are abstracted in such a way that it would prove a bit frustrating to find something :)